# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file... failed

Tags: database, database-connection

I am simply doing an exercise for my Applications Programming class.  We use Visual Studio 2012.  All I need to do is create a Service-based Database and then add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to hold mock information for "songs".  A mock database for mock information.  Everything is within VS 2012 and the files I create with it.  Every time I try to create a Serviced-based Database I get this error:

An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file \JAGUAR\Students\AHARDIN4\Exercise7\MyTunes - Baseline\MyTunes\Songs.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I'm confused.  This is supposed to be simple.  I even follow a Wizard...  I've googled this problem and every time this comes up it's a totally obscure situation compared to mine.  Someone please tell me what's going on.  I'm such a noob at this.

Comment: I answered this situation over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501185/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-file-failed (but can't flag this question as a duplicate)